# This application has no explicit mapping for /error,

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i had tried all the ways to solve the problem but why i don't know the jsp page is not displayed
yet the system.out.print in home.java is printed but jsp page is not displayed

[home.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MivKV.png)

[home.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RIM9.png)

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z4ls.png)

[embedded tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEQWv.png)

Comment: You must return "home" instead of "home.jsp"

Comment: No home is also not working, it displays the same error

Comment: Is home.jsp in the right directory? See for example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp